# Fetch all rows from A left join B based on attribute in A

Tags: mysql, performance, select, query-performance

I have 2 tables, `products` and `stores`, and a pivot table in the middle called `product_store`.

Here is the relevant portion of the table structures (from MySQL):

**products**

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`global` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

**stores**

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

**product_store**

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`show` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
```

The logic of the `global` vs `show` flags are as follows:

- If the `global` flag is 1, then assume this product is on every store, **except** when there is a `product_store` entry with `show` == 0.
- If the `global` flag is 0, then assume this product is *only* on stores where there is a `product_store` entry with `show` == 1.

In other words, `global` == 1 means show this product everywhere, `show` == 1 means show the product in this store, `show` == 0 means do not show the product in this store, and `show` takes precedence over `global`.

What I want to be able to do is fetch products based on a known store_id, where:

- products.global == 1 AND there is NO product_store entry for the product_id, store_id
- OR
- there is a product_store entry for the product_id, store_id AND product_store.show == 1

Currently I have this query, with a `GROUP BY` and a nested `SELECT` but it pulls many records from the database which are then consolidated by the `GROUP BY` and it's quite slow.  I am thinking that there must be something that's faster, without the nested select.

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, products.global, product_store.show, product_store.store_id
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN product_store ON products.id=product_store.product_id
    WHERE ((products.global=1 AND
          ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_store WHERE product_store.store_id=226 AND product_store.product_id=products.id) = 0)
         )
        OR (product_store.store_id=226 AND product_store.show=1)
        )
    GROUP BY products.id
    ;
```

`226` is the store ID in this case, I only need to run this query for one store at a time so this can be considered as a constant.

Note that if I do the above query with the `GROUP BY` then I'm getting about 14 records which is correct (when I do the count myself).  The system has a few thousand products and a few hundred stores so that product_store join table is rather large.  If I do the above query without the `GROUP BY` then I'm getting ~ 1500 records which appears to be the list of all product/product store combinations that fit the `LEFT JOIN` clause.

Just to re-iterate, the above query works fine (although in MySQL versions > 5.7.5 there will be issues with the `GROUP BY`) but it appears to be inefficient and I am trying to figure out something better and faster.

**SOME FURTHER DETAILS ON TABLE CONTENTS**

Here are some quick queries on the relevant products and stores, etc. First to show ALL relevant matching products -- there are 15, all of which have global=1.

```
SELECT products.id, MD5(products.name), products.global
    FROM products
    -- .. omitted some classification information here
    ;

+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
| id  | md5(products.name)               | global |
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
| 555 | 56e597c43cff47af57f006b7de7ff552 |      1 |
| 591 | 7ba5549546ce20e1dee02c7f6454b16f |      1 |
| 558 | 7b66d8dce0c112b3966d1940de44f9ad |      1 |
| 556 | bd3d39b9f5194184ea0853c70d7faa07 |      1 |
| 590 | ef6eccbd3795fbe70890220c09ed880d |      1 |
| 559 | b763e2b9ba305538b497da97fba066ca |      1 |
| 593 | e26744d617ed12ebffea4b996fecbbef |      1 |
| 594 | 06ba8ab6649c83577db053e4a89c1655 |      1 |
| 596 | 79f9241643e84e2a27bfc0b260432e82 |      1 |
| 595 | 85fe772dc61d27292c09a7604cf76dd7 |      1 |
| 597 | fd6c21db00e1b679c0d0d2ef8f3f6e00 |      1 |
| 560 | c8056818e3ed5885188d78a9440fa77c |      1 |
| 561 | 33d79c194e39e8e84cf743eefcd909df |      1 |
| 562 | 1c74d85823e509ab4b09e82314b09604 |      1 |
| 557 | b6a8027035b63bd4d4bd21169434426d |      1 |
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+
```

Now to look at the join with the product_store table.  There is only one entry there for store_id 226, and it has show=0.

```
SELECT products.id, MD5(products.name), products.global, product_store.show
    FROM products
    INNER JOIN product_store ON products.id=product_store.product_id
    -- omitted the classification information as per the above
    WHERE product_store.store_id=226
    ;

+-----+----------------------------------+--------+------+
| id  | MD5(products.name)               | global | show |
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+------+
| 555 | 56e597c43cff47af57f006b7de7ff552 |      1 |    0 |
+-----+----------------------------------+--------+------+
```

... I therefore need to be able to construct a query that selects all 15 products where global=1 EXCEPT the product where product_store.show=0, therefore I need the set of 14 remaining products.

Would a UNION select work somehow?  Or some form of intersect?

Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1342cf/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample, this seems to be an equivalent query:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, products.global, product_store.show, product_store.store_id
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_store
  ON products.id=product_store.product_id
 AND product_store.store_id=226
WHERE -- there is NO entry in product_store AND products.global=1
      (products.global=1 AND product_store.show IS NULL)
      -- there is an entry in product_store with show=1 
   OR (products.global=0 AND product_store.show = 1)
```

`DISTINCT` should not be neccessary.

I added this to your [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1342cf/7)

Placing conditions in `ON` vs. `WHERE` is crucial for outer joins. In `ON` it's just a condition which never filters rows but might create NULLs in the inner table. `WHERE` is applied *after* the join, and here it filters (when applied on a column of the inner table all NULLs created by the outer join will be removed again, unless you add `OR col IS NULL`).

Comment: OK that worked with one minor variation - I had to put braces () around (products.id=product_store.product_id AND product_store.store_id=226).  However, thanks, that appears to be the answer.